# Is there a way to get to a component with it's id in string format in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

In a function in the javascript's qml i have the the id of a component.
This is a simple example of what i'm trying to do:

```
function teste(val) {
    var elem = "objectId"
    var objectThatINeed = submenu1.findObjectById(elem)
    objectThatINeed.someValueIWantToChange = val
}
```

The function `findObjectById` does not exist, it's just to illustrate what i want to do.

I want to get a reference to that object (and no i dont want to access it directly like `objectId.someValueIWantToChange = val`) and then change a property.

If `id` is not acceptable another property i see that can be used is objectName, or even a custom property...

How can something like this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In QML, id is not really a property and it will be hard to retrieve it (it's more like a variable name). But you can use property like `objectName` to find a child from a specific parent:

```
Item {
        id: theParent
        Item {
            objectName: "id1"
        }
        Item {
            objectName: "id2"
        }
        Item {
            objectName: "id3"
        }
    }

    function findChild(id, root) {
        for (var i = 0; i !== root.children.length; ++i) {
            const child = root.children[i];
            if (child.objectName === id) {
                console.log("Found");
                return child;
            }
        }
                return null;
    }
```

Comment: why didn't they add something like this already

Comment: `root.children` is undefined